# What is the correct way to store a list of words in XML/RDF?

Tags: xml, rdf, vocabulary

I need to write a plug-in for Wordpress in which the admin can store a custom vocabulary. I was asked to use XML/RDF?

I need to do something like this (just an example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description>
        <word>company</word>
        <lang>en</lang>
        <singular>true</singular>
    </rdf:Description>
     <rdf:Description>
        <word>azienda</word>
        <lang>it</lang>
        <singular>true</singular>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

What is the correct formatting / xml-namespace /standard or whatsoever to do this?

PS: I don't know if it is important but the words are all related to jobs / economy / work exeperience

Comment: You are approaching this the wrong way around - if your goal is to express your vocabulary in RDF, you should _first_ model it abstractly as an RDF graph. The RDF/XML syntax then follows naturally.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra is spot on. However, if you have a task to get done and don't have time to implement Jeen's advice, start by using schema.org vocab. Use S-O terms that meet some of your requirements. Once you have that working, take the next step of addition additional vocabularies and their associated terms.